# Handle Push notification in Nativescript

Tags: javascript, android, push-notification, nativescript, telerik-appbuilder

I am working on application in Nativescript which implements push notification. Lets say server sends push notification and based on `action` mentioned in payload of notification i will have to redirect in application. This redirection should be performed if user taps on notification from drawer and application is in background. Other case when application should not redirect if its in foreground. I have managed a flag for that as follow

**app.js**

```
application.on(application.launchEvent, function (args) {
   appSettings.setBoolean('AppForground', true);
});

application.on(application.suspendEvent, function (args) {
   appSettings.setBoolean('AppForground', false);
});

application.on(application.resumeEvent, function (args) {
   appSettings.setBoolean('AppForground', true);
});

application.on(application.exitEvent, function (args) {
   appSettings.setBoolean('AppForground', false);
});

application.on(application.lowMemoryEvent, function (args) {
   appSettings.setBoolean('AppForground', false);
});

application.on(application.uncaughtErrorEvent, function (args) {
   appSettings.setBoolean('AppForground', false);
});
```

And on Push notification listener

```
 var settings = {
    // Android settings
    senderID: '1234567890', // Android: Required setting with the sender/project number
    notificationCallbackAndroid: function(data, pushNotificationObject) { // Android: Callback to invoke when a new push is received.
        var payload = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(pushNotificationObject).data);
        if (appSettings.getBoolean('AppForground') == false){
            switch (payload.action) {

                case "APPOINTMENT_DETAIL":
                    frame.topmost().navigate({
                        moduleName: views.appointmentDetails,
                        context: {
                            id: payload.id
                        }
                    });  
                    break;

                case "MESSAGE":
                    frame.topmost().navigate({
                        moduleName: views.appointmentDetails,
                        context: {
                            id: payload.id,
                            from: "messages"
                        }
                    });
                    break;

                case "REFERENCES":
                    frame.topmost().navigate({
                        moduleName: views.clientDetails,
                        context: {
                            id: payload.id,
                            name: ""
                        }
                    });
                    break;

                default: 
            }
        }
    },

    // iOS settings
    badge: true, // Enable setting badge through Push Notification
    sound: true, // Enable playing a sound
    alert: true, // Enable creating a alert

    // Callback to invoke, when a push is received on iOS
    notificationCallbackIOS: function(message) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(message));
    }
};
pushPlugin.register(settings,
    // Success callback
    function(token) {
        // if we're on android device we have the onMessageReceived function to subscribe
        // for push notifications
        if(pushPlugin.onMessageReceived) {
            pushPlugin.onMessageReceived(settings.notificationCallbackAndroid);
        }
    },
    // Error Callback
    function(error) {
        alert(error);
    }
);
```

Now the problem, is that if application is in killed state and notification arrives. Then it sets flag to `true` as application is launched which it should not. So due to that redirection is not performed and in other cases when application is in foreground state then also its navigating through pages (which should not be) on receiving notification.

I doubt about flag management is causing the problem but not sure. Would you please guide me if anything is wrong with what i did ?

**UPDATE**

I am using [push-plugin](https://github.com/NativeScript/push-plugin).

Thanks.

Comment: I would check if data after arriving to device won't have background parameter then u would be able to determine if app was background or foreground

Comment: payload does not have background parameter, Its managed locally in `app.js`. based on that i have to manage navigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this for notifications

> https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase

This plugin use FCM, it adds to datas received from notifications foreground parameter so from payload you can determine if app was background(foreground==false, app is not active or was started after notification arrived) or foreground(foreground==true, app is open and active), but you need to some changes to code as they are different plugins

Comment: I am working on In-Browser. How can i manage gradles and libraries ?

Comment: Even on the serverside i will have to make changes for sending push. Could you provide some demo/link  ?

Comment: I don't have problem to send demo of server side code but not sure how to do it app side on Appbuilder  if you are building whole app there or whats content of data from "function(data, pushNotificationObject)" from android callback?

Comment: {
    google.sent_time=1474027549237,
    smallIcon=small_icon,
    data={
        "title": "New Appointment",
        "body": "John Smith is requesting an appointment on Friday, June 23 at 9:00PM (1-hour Incall)",
        "id": 2,
        "action": "APPOINTMENT_DETAIL"
    },
    sound=1,
    title=NewAppointment,
    vibrate=1,
    google.message_id=0: 1474027549250154%d8dc7159f9fd7ecd,
    largeIcon=large_icon,
    message=JohnSmithisrequestinganappointmentonFriday,
    June23at9: 0 0PM(1-hourIncall),
    collapse_key=do_not_collapse
}

Comment: Hi can you provide me steps you followed to get it running via CLI ? Its not complete in the plugin doc.

Comment: what u mean with running via CLI?

Comment: I am not using In-Broswer. I have created project with `tns create appName`

Comment: install plugins what u need + tns plugin add nativescript-plugin-firebase and go thought guide from firebase plugin in link

Comment: I did as steps mentioned in the doc but its giving error.

Comment: `A problem occurred evaluating root project 'nativescriptappbuilderspike'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.google.gms.google-services']
   > Version: 8.4.0 is lower than the minimum version (9.0.0) required for google-services plugin.`

Comment: So for this i found 8.4.0 in `include.gradle` and changed to 9.0.0 and then 9.4.0

Comment: This error i got after resolving above error. `Execution failed for task ':buildMetadata'.
> Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1`

Comment: Try change 9.4.0 to 9.0.2 for all versions in include.gradle, maybe it would be good to join NS community at slack too :) to avoid too many comments here

Comment: Thanks it was problem of 2 different versioned Google libraries.

Comment: 1 More problem. If app is in foreground then i am able to get all json payload and if app is in backgound then just `{"foreground":false,"google.sent_time":{},"google.message_id":"0:1474461696691075%d8dc7159d8dc7159"}`

Comment: Not sure if you are using notification or data payload :/ but for this plugin on android it takes notification payload data and you should get all datas for app from `onMessageReceivedCallback: function(message) {}` callback at least that worked that way

Comment: I want to send custom array so i will have to use `data` type not `notification`. SO that i can navigate based upon received data in payload but application is crashing if i send payload in `data` type of notification.

Comment: How are you handling redirection on notification tap ?

Comment: you can use `notification { custom_tag:"data"}`  and with ui/frame `topmost().navigate({...})`

Comment: What i did is sending both `notification` and `data` and that resolved my problem.

Comment: Have you implemented FCM for ios ? i could use your help.

Comment: Not yet only planning to use that for ios too but if you create app at firebase for ios there will be guide for ios mobiles how to add firebase to them

Answer (score 0):

You can use pusher-nativescript npm module.

```
import { Pusher } from 'pusher-nativescript';
/*Observation using the above.
- Project gets build successfully.
- on run -> ERROR TypeError: pusher_nativescript__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6__.Pusher is not a constructor
- Use: import * as Pusher from 'pusher-nativescript';
- Make sure to install nativescript-websocket with this package.
*/
var pusher = new Pusher('Your_app_key', { cluster: 'your_cluster_name' });
var channel = pusher.subscribe('my-channel');
channel.bind('my-event', function(data) {
alert(JSON.stringify(data));
});
```